# Laravel Eloquent for sale-product-customer relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, eager-loading

So using **Laravel 4**, I have a **Sales** table that has a many to many relationship with a **Products** table, and it also has a one to many relation with a **Customers** table.

I set up my models as follows:

```
class Sale extends Eloquent {
...
    public function products(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Product');
    }
    public function customers(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Customer');
    }
}

class Product extends Eloquent {
...
    public function sales(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Sale');
    }
}

class Customer extends Eloquent {
...
    public function sales(){
    return $this->hasMany('Sale');
    }
}
```

What I want to do is return the data of all sales, including the data of each product included in each sale and the data of the customer that bought it.

In my **SalesController** I'm using eager loading to query my data like this:

```
public function index()
{
    return Sale::with('products', 'customers')->get();
}
```

It returns an object with the Sale data, the Product data, but the Customer data is null.

How can I achieve this using Eloquent (or a custom query)?

**EDIT**

This is the object string it returns:

```
[{"id":1,"customer_id":1,"date":"2013-11-21","status":1,"created_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","products":[{"id":1,"name":"Monitor","price":50,"status":1,"created_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","pivot":{"sale_id":1,"product_id":1,"custom_price":25,"order":1}}],"customers":null}]
```

Comment: As I see you are doing it right. I think problem lies else where.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your code. In sales model, shouldn't it be `customer` in singular to represent a 1:n relationship?

Comment: Can we see the data definitions?  Does the sales table have a customer_id field?

Comment: @J.T.Grimes: My Sales table has:
`id,
customer_id,
date,
status`

Customer has basic customer data, and Product has basic product data.

Comment: @ManuelPedrera I changed it to singular and it worked! Awesome!!
Can you put your comment as answer so I can accept it as correct??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `customers` relationship to singular:

```
class Sale extends Eloquent {
...
    public function products(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Product');
    }
    public function customer(){ // <- here
        return $this->belongsTo('Customer');
    }
}
```

(Moved from comments to answer)